# Losing info when using update query c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Hi I'm trying to use the update query to update a column or even a whole row, however when I only update a certain column i get "no value given for one or more required parameters". how can i use the code for both updating column and row also?

here's my code:

```
protected void updateButtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var myConnection = GetConnection())
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        // You should be using a parameterized query here
        using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update client set username = ?, [name] = ?, surname = ?, [email] = ?, [password] = ? where id = ?", myConnection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", txt_uname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[name]", txt_name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("surname", txt_sname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[email]", txt_email.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[password]", txt_password.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[id]", txt_id.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if one of those text boxes is empty, you're supplying a null value as a parameter.  That's why you are getting the no value given error.

You can solve this problem by doing:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[name]", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_name.Text) ?
     (object)DBNull.Value : txt_name.Text);
```

This will set the column value to null if the textbox is empty.

You could do something like this if you want to only update fields that have been filled out:

```
string cmd = "update blah set ";
bool shouldUpdate = false;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name_textbox))
{
    shouldUpdate = true;    
    cmd += "name = ?,"; don't add the comma for the last one
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name",name_textbox.Text);
}
... do this for each of your text boxes
if (shouldUpdate)
{
    cmd += "where id = ?";
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id",id);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

but that is kinda ugly and I would recommend making sure the textboxes are populated with the current data when you're loading the page.

Comment: i tried your code and I'm getting this error: Error 1 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'string' @David Greilach

Comment: Sorry about that.  I edited my answer.  In order for that to work you will need to cast DBNull.Value to object.  Also make sure you have all the columns as Scott said in his answer.

Comment: This isn't right. The table would be perfectly happy to accept empty strings as parameter values. While that won't result in the outcome the OP is looking for, it's not the error he complained about in the question, either. Look to the other answer for the real problem.

Comment: I tried your updated code and there's no errors however i'm getting the same problem when updating I lose all info from the rest of the columns.  Thanks @David Greilach

Comment: are you populating the text boxes with the existing data.  With the way your update statement is set up, you will overwrite the existing data with null if you submit with an empty textbox. You want to only update a column if a value has been entered in the textbox?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add a parameter for `[health issues]`, that is the missing column the error is yelling at you about.

```
 protected void clientUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var myConnection = GetConnection())
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        using (var cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update client set [name] = ?, surname = ?, [date of birth] = ?, [health issues] = ?, [yoga experience] = ?, [email] = ?, [phone number] = ?, [home address] = ?, [password] = ? where id = ?", myConnection))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[name]", txt_name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("surname", txt_sname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[date of birth]", txt_dob.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[health issues]", txt_HealthIssues.Text); \\ <---- This was missing.
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[yoga experience]", txt_exp.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[email]", txt_email.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[phone number]", txt_phone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[home address]", txt_address.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[password]", txt_password.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", txt_id.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to only update 1 column you need to write a new query that does not include the other parameters in the query. Traditionally people will use a [ORM library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like Entity Framework to make this easier to do. You will need to check and see if you can find a ORM library that is compatible with your OleDb connection objects.

Also, if you do not go with a ORM you [may want to not use AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), it has to make assumptions about what datatypes your code is and you can sometimes get large performance problems due to indexes not being used correctly when it guesses wrong.

Comment: Hehe I thought you might be :)